# Are "hurt" interchangeable with "harm" in this case?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

*The slowing development of the real estate sector will hurt/harm the overall economical growth.*

"Hurt" to me is often used with somebody or one's feelings. It has connotation of "pain. So I prefer "harm" to "hurt" in this case, what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that 'hurt' has a connotation to being in pain or feeling pain. However, I believe damage or disturb can also be used in the context. Overall, the understanding for the sentence is that the situation has an implication towards pain as an effect.

Answer (score 1):

Both verbs can be used transitively  suggesting damage caused  to people or things. Referring to the economy, *hurt* appears to be more widely used. (see Ngram below).

[To hurt:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Hurt) : (from TFD)

> - To cause physical damage or pain to; injure.
> - To cause physical damage to; harm: *The frost hurt the orange crop.*
> - To be detrimental to; hinder or impair: *The scandal hurt the candidate's chances for victory.*

[To harm:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/harm)

> - to do or cause harm to; injure; damage; hurt: *to harm one's reputation.*
> - to injure physically, morally, or mentally.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=harm%20the%20economy%2Churt%20the%20economy&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Charm%20the%20economy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Churt%20the%20economy%3B%2Cc0): harm the economy vs hurt the economy.